# SUSDB appears to be in a different location than shown in SQL Studio

Tags: sql-server-2014

I Have WSUS installed on a 2012R2 server.  I am using SQL, not the internal windows database.

I was looking at cleaning out some old files.  One of the folders is named RestoreTemp (created to restore data to check).  The SUSDB.mdf and SUSDB.log files there have more recent date modified values than the files located where I would expect them to be (Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL12.WSUS/MSSQL/DATA).  When I check the file location in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, it shows the database as being located in the correct location.  However, the date modified is almost 2 weeks before today (the one in the incorrect location shows today's date and very close to the current time).  There are no other files in the incorrect location.

I didn't do any type of database restore for quite some time (I do at least quarterly to verify that backups are working), definitely not within the past couple of weeks.

Anyone have any idea of what is going on?  WSUS is set to synchronize daily, and when I look at the Synchronizations there were some on a date after the date shown on the database in the correct location so I am pretty sure this is not the database being used.  I would like to have the database in the correct location so someone doesn't delete the one in the incorrect location but am afraid I will blow up WSUS.

Thank you in advance for any information you can provide.

Comment: Date modified is pretty useless for your intentions. It does not change every time data is written to the file, it only changes with significant changes such as a growth or shrink. It is not a valid way to determine the file that is being used by SQL Server. Check `master.sys.master_files` and/or `thatdatabase.sys.database_files` and believe that over assumptions made from what Windows Explorer or even the SSMS UI tells you.